# How to get data between 2 dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have some case when I want to get data between dates. I want to return data between the dates, it always gives me the wrong result.

I tried using, example :

```
date1 >= '1-28-2019' && date2 <= '2-8-2019'
```

it always show the wrong result.

```
let created_on = new Date(task['created-on'])
let month = created_on.getMonth() + 1 
let date = created_on.getDate()
let year = created_on.getFullYear()
let date_now = new Date()
let year_now = date_now.getFullYear()

let combine = month + '-' + date

console.log(combine >= '1-28' && combine <= '2-8' && year_now == year)
```

I want to get data from date 1-28 to date 2-8 and present year. But it gives the wrong result, is there any problem in my code?

Thank You for answering this question.

Comment: This is because - `8` > `18` in string comparison. You can do it in various way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `slice`

```
    function leadingZero(str, len = 2) {
        return (new Array(len).fill(0).join('') + str).slice(-len);
    }
    let combine = leadingZero(month) + '-' + leadingZero(date);
    // 0128 for `1-28`, 0208 for `2-8`
```

2. Use `Number`

```
    let combine = month * 100 + day;
    // 128 for `1-28` 208 for `2-8`
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

`new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);`

```js
let task = { 'created-on': new Date(2019, 1, 6) };
let created_on = new Date(task['created-on'])
let month = created_on.getMonth(); // Use index
let date = created_on.getDate()
let year = created_on.getFullYear()
let date_now = new Date()
let year_now = date_now.getFullYear()

// let combine = month + '-' + date

let startDate = new Date(year_now, 0, 28); // 0 - Jan
let endDate = new Date(year_now, 1, 8); // 1 - Feb

// direct compare with `created_on`
console.log(created_on >= startDate && created_on <= endDate); // year will be same if comparison is `true`

// compare with constructed date
let combine = new Date(year, month, date);
console.log(combine >= startDate && combine <= endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a date object from your string date, and compare them.

```
date1 >= new Date(2019, 0, 28) && date2 <= new Date(2019, 1, 8)
```

As said by David784, one of the multiple Date constructor is **Date(year, monthIndex, day)**. monthIndex starts from **0 (January)** to **11 (December)** according to the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters).

Comment: Important note: the [Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) takes an "Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December."

Answer (score 0):

You are getting wrong results because you expect to compare dates (like `1-28` and `2-8`), but you are actually comparing strings! (Note that `combine` is a string).

What you should do is compare dates. You can do it by setting a year, `whatever_year`, just for the purpose of comparing the dates, and it should work as expected.

```js
let created_on = new Date(task['created-on']);
let month = created_on.getMonth() + 1;
let date = created_on.getDate();
let year = created_on.getFullYear();
let date_now = new Date();
let year_now = date_now.getFullYear();

let whatever_year = '1500';
let combine = new Date(month + '-' + date + '-' + whatever_year);

let date1 = new Date('1-28-' + whatever_year);
let date2 = new Date('2-8-' + whatever_year);
console.log(combine >= date1 && combine <= date2 && year_now == year);
```